# ¿Como recibir dos parámetros o mas enviados por ajax en un método controlador PHP MVC?

Tags: php, ajax, mvc

Hola eh intentado muchas cosas pero no logro resolver esta duda tengo esta funcion ajax

```
 $("#mySelect").on("change.select2", function (e) {
    const val1 = 20
    const val2 = 30;
    const ajaxUrl = base_url + "/url_base/metodo/" + id + "/" + type;
    sendAjaxRequest("POST", ajaxUrl, null, function (response) {
        console.log(response)
    });
  });
```

en ajaxUrl se genera una url de este tipo = /pagina/controlador/metodo/31/1

y en el metodo del controlador intento recibir sus parametros asi

```
public function datos($val1,$val2)
    {
        echo $val1;
        echo $val2;
    }
```

Pero recibo este error:
`Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function MiController::datos(), 1 passed`

si acaso decido usar el metodo asi

```
public function datos($val1)
    {
        echo $val1;
    }
```

ahi si funciona ya que me muestra el valor enviado desde ajax pero soy incapaz de recibir los dos valores. ¿Cual podria ser el problema?

Comment: ¿Usas algún framework?

Comment: no php puro con mvc en este caso

Answer (score 0):

Y si intentas enviarlos de esta forma

```
const data = { val1: val1, val2: val2 };
sendAjaxRequest("POST", ajaxUrl, data, function (response) {
    console.log(response)
});
```

Y luego recibirlos del otro lado como

```
public function datos()
{
    $val1 = $_POST['val1'];
    $val2 = $_POST['val2'];
    echo $val1;
    echo $val2;
}
```